# Angular getting Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token while accessing URLs from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following json and I am pulling `tweeturl` from it

```
{
  "name": "Lifehacker",
  "handle": "@lifehacker",
  "avatar": "images/lifehacker.png",
  "time": "1h",
  "tweet": "Workflow, the nifty automation app on iOS, just got a heck of a lot easier to use: ",
  "attachments": {
    "media": "image",
    "url": "images/twitter.jpg"
  },
  "tweeturl": "http://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM",
  "interaction": {
    "like": "2m",
    "retweet": "5k"
  }
}
```

and displaying it like this:

```
<a href="{{tweets.tweeturl}}" ng-show="{{tweets.tweeturl}}">{{tweets.tweeturl}}</a>
```

but everytime it executes I get the URL but also receive errors on console saying

`Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [http://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM] starting at [://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM].`

I am pretty new to angular any help and explanation will be appreciated

Comment: do you know what `ng-show` is for?

Comment: To show the elements if the condition holds true

Comment: does `http://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM` look like "a condition" to you?

Comment: I have also tried `{{tweets.tweeturl}}!=''` but it gives error `Syntax Error: Token '!=' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression`

Comment: As @JaromandaX eludes to ... the ng-show directive is misused and causing your issue.

Comment: How can I fix it? I have tried like this `{{tweets.tweeturl}}!=''` and this `'{{tweets.tweeturl}}'!=''` but doesn't seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-show` expects an **expression** (e.g. a name of a defined in the scope variable, that evaluates to *truthy* or *falsy* value), not a **string**.

You don't have to interpolate it using `{{ }}` syntax. Just pass the variable directly:

```
<a href="{{tweets.tweeturl}}" ng-show="tweets.tweeturl">{{tweets.tweeturl}}</a>
```

When you write `ng-show="{{tweets.tweeturl}}"` instead, what happens is Angular first interpolates `{{tweets.tweeturl}}` to `http://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM` - and then it tries to treat it as an expression, so it's like you'd try to write a javascript like this:

```
function someFunction () {
   var abc = '123';
   http://lifehac.kr/L18xlfM    // <- this is not a correct expression
   return abc;
}
```

Comment: you should also use `ng-href` in case it has not finished digesting when the user clicks. link to angular doc for [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Comment: Yeah, `ng-url` and `ng-href` solved the issue for me, Thanks for the valuable tips :)

Answer (score 1):

If I could give some examples of how to use ng-show and ng-href would be this two.

First, I would put an $scope or $this variable on my controller and assign it the JSON answer you get from your service($http ???). Then set an error variable to true or false.

```
     $http.get("tweets.json").then(function(response) {
        //First function handles success
        $scope.content = response.data;
        $scope.errorGet = false;
        }, function(response) {
      //Second function handles error
      $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
      $scope.errorGet = true;
    });
```

Given that you can now know in certainty if you get or did not get your Json Tweet, you could refactor in your view:

```
<a href="{{tweets.tweeturl}}" ng-show="errorGet">{{tweets.tweeturl}}</a>
```

Now that we are set, I need to explain why you shouldn't use href and insted use ng-href. It happens that the expressions {{ }} could be evaluated before you make click on the link.

So, the correct way to refactor your code is this:

```
<a ng-href="{{tweets.tweeturl}}" ng-show="errorGet">{{tweets.tweeturl}}</a>
```

Link to the ng-href doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Hope it helps